# Prebid.js - setup SmartAdserver steps as DFP, is it possible ?

Tags: javascript, double-click-advertising, prebid.js

Hi i'm using Sovrn's header bidding solution called **Header complete** (based on prebid.js) on one of my sites using DFP. 
I have another site configured with SmartAdserver as Adserver to deliver ads and I dont know if it's possible to setup SMartAdserver to install completely the prebid solution. 
Is there any adapter ?

THanks in advance.

Comment: Hii did manage to setup prebid with smart server? would you mind to provide some source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use key-value to pass the price bucket and set up multiple eCPM line items that target each price bucket
https://support.smartadserver.com/s/article/ka00Y000000Z3HAQA0/Using-keyword-targeting